# Error in display of Pointcloud in /base_link frame

Tags: ros, rviz, base-link, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to view a pointcloud2 message in rviz in /base_link frame. So i wrote a static transform publisher which published a tf base_link->camera_link.  The pointcloud2 can be successfully viewed when fixed frame is camera_depth_frame  but when i select fixed frame to be base_link the display stops and the pointcloud2 message in Rviz turns red.

What could be possibly wrong..?  I am supplying the required Tf, then why does the pointcloud2 message does not transform to /base_link frame.

P.S.

1.During the above process the target frame is always filled with the option of fixed frame

2.The source of all the data is a bag file from Kinect.

3.Also i run roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch load_driver:=false.
EDIT: Added the screenshot
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52788/error-in-display-of-pointcloud-in-/base_link-frame/) by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 263 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-01-19**:
Sounds like a problem with your transforms (what does the red text say?). Please run `rosrun tf view_frames` and upload the output somewhere.

**Comment by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on 2013-01-19**:
The error says "Message removed because it is too old" could this be because i didnt record the tf message at the time i recorded the bag file from Kinect..? But i also ran  rosparam set use_sim_time true

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-01-19**:
Your tf-tree looks fine. Try disabling use_sim_time. Or if you leave it enabled, make sure that you are adding the `--clock` parameter to `rosbag play`

**Comment by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on 2013-01-20**:
Hey the problem found to be was that i didn't record tf messages at the time I recorded the Kinect data. So later when I played the data using rosbag --clock parameter , i also had to play the tf_broadcaster with --clock parameter. With this the error disappeared..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar issue, I had to use the following param.. rosparam set /use_sim_time true  along with the --clock by Ben_S

---

Originally posted by [jimbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4830/jimbo/) with karma: 36 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0